# ComException while Data Binding in XAML Metro app

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, microsoft-metro

I am getting a COM Exception while binding ListView to a List items. The Exception is being thrown from the 2nd line here. "A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in app.exe

Additional information: Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))"

```
Playlists = content.getPlayLists();
PlayListView.DataContext = Playlists;
```

XAML declaring the binding

```
<ListView x:Name="PlayListView" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Playlists}" Background="AntiqueWhite" SelectionChanged="PlayListView_SelectionChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="364" Margin="56,268,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="308">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

I simplified the PlayList by just having 2 strings but still has the same issue.

```
public class PlayList
{
    private string playListName;
    private string description;
    private DateTime dateTimeCreated;
    private int numTracks;
    private List<Track> tracks;
    private string id;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return playListName; }
        set { playListName = value; }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return description; }
        set { description = value; }
    }

    public DateTime CreatedDate
    {
        get { return dateTimeCreated; }
        set { dateTimeCreated = value; }
    }

    public int NumberOfTracks
    {
        get { return numTracks; }
        set { numTracks = value; }
    }

    public List<Track> Tracks
    {
        get { return tracks; }
        set { tracks = value; }
    }

    public String Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, some things never change, COM error reporting was always rather poor.  The real catastrophe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to not setting the UI element on main thread. I fixed it using

```
PlayListView.Dispatcher.Invoke(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, (s, a) => 
{ 
    PlayListView.DataContext = Playlists; 
}, PlayListView, null);
```